# Does Puppet continue to run after startup when used as a provisioner in Vagrant?

Tags: vagrant, puppet

The question is basically in the title, but to expound a little: I've got a puppet manifest that runs on startup in our development Vagrant VMs. I'd like to add a couple things that make life easier for our developers -- things like bouncing Apache when our source files change or rebuilding our translation files when the master file is changed.

All of that seems simple enough to do, but I'm not sure whether it's possible to make the puppet service continue to monitor the machine after the VM is provisioned, and the Vagrant documentation doesn't seem to mention it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provisioning is a part of the `vagrant up` process, once the VM is up and running, it's finished.

> NOTE: Provisioners in Vagrant allow you to automatically install software, alter configurations, and more on the machine as part of the vagrant up process.

I am NOT an expert on Puppet (Chef user), I think to bounce Apache if config files are changed, you may need an agent running on the VM.

BTW: `vagrant provision` can be used to run updated Chef cookbooks or Puppet modules after the VM is up.

#### Update

Since Vagrant 1.3.0 (released Sep 5, 2013)

- `vagrant up` will now only run provisioning by default the first time it is run. Subsequent `reload` or `up` will need to explicitly specify the `--provision` flag to provision. [GH-1776]

See change log => https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Comment: Thanks. That was what I suspected but I hadn't been able to find anyone to confirm and I wanted to make sure that my tests weren't just doing something wrong.

Comment: It is NOT clearly documented, it was based on what I've been observing since vagrant 1.0. Also I've looked into Vagrant source code, pretty much confirmed the provisioning is one-off when `up`.